# Get %ebp ,%esp in C and output value in stack

Tags: c, x86

Currently, I am working a problem that I need to output some values in the call stack. Here's what I did:

```
int funcA() 
{ 
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    char c = '3';
    asm("mov %ebp, ebp");
    asm("mov %esp, esp");
    printf("&a = %x\n", &a);
    printf("&b = %x\n", &b);
    printf("&c = %x\n", &c);
    printf("esp = %X  ebp = %X\n", esp, ebp);
}
```

esp and ebp have been declared in advance. The output of the code above is:

```
&a = ff7f7c
&b = ff7f78
&c = ff7f77
esp = FF7F68  ebp = FF7F88
```

1. Why &c = ff7f77? In the stack, every chunk should equal to 4 bytes regardless of its type, right?
2. why esp = ff7f68? I think it should equal to &c-4
3. Another question is that if I did this:

   ```
   printf("%x", ebp-4);
   ```

The outpus is

```
ff7f78
```

Can anybody explain why the output is not ff7f84 to me?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: "In the stack, every chunk should equal to 4 bytes regardless of its type, right?" - no, that's how alignment works. (Also, how would you fit a 64-bit integer in 4 bytes, assuming a 8-bit byte?)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the compiler can do whatever it wants.
2. No, the compiler can do whatever it wants.
3. You probably declared `ebp` as something other than `char *`.  You're seeing the results of pointer arithmetic.  In this case it looks like it's a pointer to a 4-byte type.  You shouldn't be using `%x` to print a pointer anyway.  That's what `%p` is for.

Comment: I changed %x to %p and the output is esp = pff7f77  ebp = pff7f77. I have no idea why they are equivalent. In addition, you are right, I didn't declare esp and ebp as  char *.